# 2003 Trailblazer XL 6 cyl

Tags: chevrolet, ac, trailblazer

I just replaced my battery today well now once I turn on my air conditioner my car starts to lose power and even shuts off. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest it hasn't much to do with the battery. Have you been running your AC all along and now it just sort of doesn't work so well, or ??

Comment: How does it lose power? Electrically?

Answer (score 1):

The throttle body is dirty.  Over time, the PCM compensates for this so you never never realize it.  When the battery was disconnected, the PCM forgot all about those learned values, and now it is operating as if you had a clean throttle body.

Clean it, then do another battery disconnect and you should be good to go.